# Is there a way to set CORS policy solely for a SignalR hub in ASP.NET Core 2.2 MVC?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-core, signalr

I have an ASP.NET Core 2.2 MVC project and I need to set CORS policy specifically for SignalR hub but not globally (not for all controllers and actions). If I follow recommendations by adding `app.UseCors()` it works but globally and I need to apply the policy only for SignalR. Is there a way to do that?

I have tried [this](https://forums.asp.net/t/2033309.aspx?Calling%20SignalR%20hub%20from%20other%20domain%20via%20CORS) too but with no success.

**EDIT 2019-07-22 18:33 CEST**

Here is CORS policy I use:

```
services.AddCors(o =>
            {
                o.AddPolicy("MyCorsPolicy", b =>
                {
                    b.AllowAnyHeader()
                    .AllowAnyMethod()
                    .SetIsOriginAllowed(s => true)
                    .AllowCredentials();
                });
            });
```

Comment: you have to define cors policies.

Comment: Sorry, I should have explain more. I have defined CORS policy but I still do not see how to apply it only to SignalR hub but not overall.

Comment: I believe you need to use *something* like `app.Map("/signalr", map =>
{
    map.UseCors(...);
    map.RunSignalR(...);
});`

Comment: I have tried it but .RunSignalR(...) does not exist in 2.2 and I tried with UseSignalR(...) and the result is the same CORS policy issue.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After hours of attempts I had to turn to GitHub and this is what Brennan Conroy suggested: https://github.com/aspnet/AspNetCore/issues/12564

And it works!

**Edit 2019-07-29 13:40 CEST**

This is what helped:

```
app.Map("/path", c =>
{
    c.UseCors("somePolicy");
    c.UseSignalR(route =>
    {
        route.MapHub<MyHub>("/hub");
    });
});
```

And clients will connect to the hub via "/path/hub".

Comment: Please consider extracting the essential part that solved the issue into the answer. Links can (and will) break.